# Joy.msgs line44 problem

Tags: ros, arduino, ros-melodic, sensor-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, when i want to open the Joy.msg file in the sensor_msgs directory for arduino, i get the following error:
Parsing Joy.msg as OLE file failed at /usr/bin/msgconvert line 44.

For spesification I first installed the msgconverter and tried the following code in terminal:
msgconvert Joy.msg

I cannot see the inside of the message file, how can i solve this problem or see the message file's inside?
Thanks for help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/347303/joy.msgs-line44-problem/) by [TheUltimateQuestionAsker99](https://answers.ros.org/users/52780/theultimatequestionasker99/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-03-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`Joy.msg` is a text file. It would seem your platform/OS is telling the Arduino IDE it's an "OLE file".

There is no need to convert the `.msg` file, you should just open it as a regular text file.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-23**:
Actually: it's a `.yaml` file, but with a different extension. So if you'd like to benefit from syntax highlighting, tell your IDE it's a `.yaml` file.